# What apps do program in C++ nowadays

Tags: c++

With RoR, Java, C#, PHP etc.. what do people use C++ for these days?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about taking a poll

Answer (score 12):

You're comparing apples to oranges. Languages such as PHP, Ruby, and Python are scripting languages. They a) are interpreted, and b) don't provide the kind of low-level memory access that C++ does, and thus aren't suitable for things that need to talk directly to hardware. Java and C# both run in a runtime environment on top of a particular platform and for the same reason aren't always the best choice. In all of these cases, things such as garbage collection can get in the way of speed and performance.

Languages are just tools; you choose the best tool for the task at hand. Just because higher-level languages make many tasks easier for a particular application domain doesn't mean that lower level languages don't have their place.

Answer (score 8):

C++ is the preferred language when the user experience is more important than
development cost.

Performance. When Users time is valuable enough to spend some extra development hours.

Stability. Other languages may quick whip up something of descent quality.
  But If you want it flawless, C++ is a better choise. As usual in c++ it is both
  easier to get it totally wrong and totally right, depending on your skill and time available.

Ease of use. You can deliver a single binary that works everywhere. No need
  for inexperienced end user to fiddle with installling runtimes and
  interpreters, worring about VM versions and GC tweaking.

Users resources. Just because the user has 2gb of ram doesn't mean that she
  wants our program to use all of it.

Usability. If you want specialized non-standard streamlined user interface.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with these points you're talking about local applications, but I doubt most web applications are written in C++, and in general I find web apps to be fast enough and have a relatively consistent interface.

Comment: Most web apps are N-tier systems, and the lowest tier or two is quite often written in C or C++.  The top tier would be JavaScript, then some dynamic web page generation system (PHP, ASP, JSP, whatever), and then at minimum some kind of database, which is usually C or C++.  That's the usual pattern, but it's often helpful to add another tier between the web layer and the DB layer, which can well be in C or C++.  There's also the web server itself, which you can consider to be a layer between the server-side web code and the DB layer.

Answer (score 5):

Something that seems to have been overlooked so far are projects where there is already a substantial C or C++ code base.  Most programming work is not going into creating brand new programs.  If you are so blessed as to be creating something completely *de novo*, great, but that's not the common situation.

It's possible to mix languages, of course, so you can have the old C++ core program with additional code written in some other language.  But, this is not easy, for a number of reasons:

1. There's the impedance mismatch between the languages themselves.  Try to send a C++ std::multiset to Perl.  It's kind of like an associative array, but not really.  You end up using lowest-common-denominator data structures, avoiding anything that's specific to only one of the two languages.  You then lose out on some of the features you were trying to gain by mixing languages.
2. You have to spend a lot of effort to define some kind of API between the two parts of the program.  Most programs are not already architected to have such a layer.  Refactoring and packaging the old core functionality to provide this is not easy, and it's ongoing work as the program's scope expands.
3. You either have to integrate the interpreter for the other language into the old C++ core, or you have to run it as a separate program and arrange for coordination between these two different programs.  They must start up and shut down together, they have to maintain their IPC channels, etc.
4. Having overcome all the above, you will frequently find yourself needing to write code for both halves of the program.  You will always have some delay while your brain makes a kind of mental context shift between the two languages.  It never drops to 0 delay.  This soaks up some of the superior productivity of the higher-level language.  This is especially bad when working on a new feature in the high-level code that requires adding something to the old C++ core, so you're constantly bouncing between the two.  It can be done, but it's a drag on productivity, the main claimed advantage from switching to some other language.

Answer (score 4):

Two of the most common usage of C++ I would think are graphical interfaces and video games programming.

Answer (score 4):

Almost everything on the desktop (except paint.net)

Everything on the server that RoR, php etc is running on top of (any language that can't write it's own compiler is probably written in C++)

Anything embedded smaller than an iPhone

Anything with a lot of computation - that isn't in Fortran ;-)   Yes I know C# performance has improved, anybody got round to rewriting LAPACK, BLAS or NAG in it yet?

edit -
Is there a badge for most comments?

This is why SO doesn't work for discussions. Notice the order of comments change as they are voted. If you want to have childish arguements there is always reddit.

Comment: Surely you don't mean to suggest that C++ is more suited to (Windows) desktop development than C#?

Comment: C++ is more suited for cross platform desktop development though. Who cares about C# if it doesn't have GUI libs/frameworks that will work on linux, osx and windows?

Comment: That's why I wrote "Windows" .. read along with me now .. W I N D O W S

Comment: @Ben: It isn't a question of whether C# or C++ is more suited to Windows or not.  It's a question of 20 years of inertia.  Look around, you'll find stats showing how .NET has utterly and completely failed to wipe C++ from the face of Windows.  Technically better and newer are not sufficient reasons to throw out an entrenched technology.

Comment: Windows development, especially desktop?  Definitely Delphi.

Comment: @Ben This is almost the 10th year for C#. What desktop killer app is there to compare with applications built on desktop using C++, even on windows!

Comment: @Warren: Since you're the one making the categorical statement, why don't you provide the stats yourself?

Comment: "that isn't in Fortran" sent shivers up my spine.  We have a legacy piece of S...oftware, that was written by theoretical and math folk orginally.  They weren't taught programming, they were taugh Fortran, the language, that all, no data structures, no CS theory, no best practices, just the language that is it.  Management won't pay to rewrite it, they won't even buy the Tums.

Comment: @AraK: what defines a killer app on Windows? One that everyone uses? Or knows about? What C++ app (that doesn't have its origins in the previous decade) can you say that about?

Comment: Google Chrome, Notepad++, 'I bet every game out there is also built using C++'... Just give me one application that is built using C# to compare! even the C# compiler is still in C++.

Comment: I'm not really sure what point some of you guys are trying to make is.  All of the desktop Windows "killer apps" that I can think of are 10+ years old, so of course they are C++.  Pretty much all of the "killer apps" of the 2000s have been web apps; except for maybe iTunes, and that's by Apple...

Comment: @Bruce McGee: "Windows development, especially desktop? Definitely Delphi." : Funny, in a 1990 way... ^_^ ...

Comment: @Ben M: You are asking others the burden of proof (your comment to Warren), all the while dodging the question yourself (your answer to AraK). So I turn around the question for you "What C# app can you say that about?", that is, could you give us C# programs names that are either well known by either elite users (a compiler IDE, a flight simulator), or by common users (a word processor, a browser)?

Comment: @paercebal: I'm laughing all the way to the bank. In the mean time, I'm just sitting back and enjoying the C# vs C++ "discussion".  :)

Comment: @paercebal: I asked Warren for proof of the statistical claims which he made--and I didn't dodge AraK's question: I questioned its relevance, since whether or not there's a "killer app" on Windows written in C# is a red herring; you might just as fairly ask how many new applications are being written in C++ vs C#. If AraK's question is biased towards C++ (since killer apps are almost always mature apps), then that question is probably biased towards C#. I'm sure we can think of loads more biased questions that have nothing to do with reality. And I'm still waiting for Warren.

Comment: @Ben: First, all I'm doing is pointing out that even if we grant your original suitability claim, it doesn't tell us anything about which languages are actually being used.  I said you could easily find stats showing this.  A little Googling yields: http://langpop.com/ http://www.google.com/trends?q=c%2B%2B%2C+c%23 and http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/  And re killer apps, I'm aware of more new C++ programs than C# ones. Adobe Lightroom (C++ and Lua) and Luxology modo come to mind.  Please point to a C# app of this caliber.  (Try both programs' demos.  They're awesome.)

Comment: @Eugene: Surely you don't mean to imply that C++ is the best choice for cross platform development? In many ways, C++ is less portable than Java or C#, simply because it compiles native code. You can write portable code, but it is much more difficult than running on a VM.

Answer (score 3):

Anything where performance is a high priority. Garbage collection, HTML rendering, animation, games, intensive computation...

Answer (score 2):

And from personal experience Computer-aided Design (CAD) plugins/addins are also C++, especially if you want to target multiple CAD systems (e.e Pro/Engineer, SoludWorks, CATIA, UG, AutoCAD etc).

Answer (score 1):

While other languages have come along.  Many poeple who have used C++ in the past aren't just going to jump bandwagon with Java or C#.  Linux all well and good in it's own right, but the majority of the computer Market still belongs to the Evil Empire.  Java is NOT the dominant language there, no matter how much the religeous zelots claim it to be.  Actually in small business apps, VB is king.  I think I saw one figure giving it 58% of internal development for GUI front ends.  C# is picking up momentum, but I suspect it primarily from the younger crowd who are less set in there ways.  You can argue till your blue in the face virtues of a new language with someone who's been using a language for 15 years, and they just won't care.  "Oh that's neat." and they turn back around and continue typing their C++.

Edit:

OS development, C maybe C++.

Tool & Langauge development, C maybe C++.

Industrial control, C, C++, Labview in somecases, FPGA development and NO trendy languages.

Embedded alot of C, some C++ and some assembly required.

(The IPhone is a general purpose palm computer, with phone capability.  Not special
   purpose computer designed for a singular purpose.)

PS3 C, C++ and some assembly required.

XBox360 Some C#, mostly C++ and some C and again some assembly required.

GPU Programming?  It ain't PHP that's for DAMN sure.

Windows Programming C++, C#, and even some C still, VB.

Edit:

@Jeff L:
The Cult following that many these language have, I find irrational and distasteful.  I start edging away from anyone who waxes poetic about ANY language, it's just mental.  It's not a matter of opinion that professionally sold applications AREN'T written in Java for Window, it's fact.  I'm sorry, but it's true.  Maybe in the IT world it's useful, but not for shrink wrapped Windows software.  I write embedded software, and the "feature" of not having pointers means that in order to do any practical work there or on OSs and device drivers requires hacks that violate the language it's self.  There are cases where you have to "fly without a net" and the interpretive languages are designed SPECIFICALLY not to let you do that.

And not to be too argumentative with, but the heritage code base is a hard issue to get around.  While we write new code in C and C++, I can't even get management PAY to upgrade old code written in Fortran or Ada to C or C++ forget Java that requires a whole new coding standard and butt loads procedures and documentation have to update, that cost even more.  And unless the only software you write is GPL and freeware, who's paying for it is the primary concern.  And in many cases "if it's isn't broke don't fix it" doesn't even apply, "if it's broke and no one bitching, we're not paying to fix" is managements choice.

Comment: I would add Matlab to industrial control and embedded

Comment: I guess they do have the "DSP toolkit." I personally only use it at the office mostly for data analysis.  Most of our targets are C/C++, but have been recently been becoming pure FPGAs replacing processor in some cases.

Comment: I really disagree that the prominence of C++ has as much to do with the platform (UNIX, Windows, embedded, etc) as it does with the application domain of the project. To argue that C++ only still exists because people are "set in their ways" or because Microsoft doesn't use Java is a bit off base. If you're a developer and can't use newer languages that are better suited to a particular task just because it's outside of your comfort zone, then you shouldn't be in the industry.

Comment: Better suited to a particular task is a only matter of opinion.  C++ folks don't buy into the VM languages easily.  I've only heard one arguement that satified me in all the "Silver Bullet" noise out there.  The notion that a VM runtime can know what processor advancements have occured since the original development of the application.  The majority of the rest of it is opinion, and conjecture.  "Silver Bullet's" don't fix bad programmers, and good programmers don't need them.  I was highly enthusiastic about Java when it first came out, but failed to live up to the fanfare.

Answer (score 1):

Backends to projects.  Many projects are written in multiple languages, where all the backend operations are written in C++ where APIs to other languages are provided.

The best project I can think of that does this is GNU Radio.  Basically, how GNU Radio works is that all the DSP blocks (modulators, filters, etc) are written in C++.  However, you make your radio using python, that is you connect the blocks together in python.

Comment: @Pete Eddy - maybe in your world Fortran is obsolete, but it isn't by a long shot. Neither is Cobol or RPG. Keep dreaming. And your Delphi link is BS. It's a misguided opinion.

Comment: @xcramps. Sorry if the sarcasm of the "But that's just obsolete" didn't bleed through.  And it's not MY Delphi link, it was the Bruce McGee's post, and found it very interesting.  I don't know how I put the comment on the wrong answer.  I know that Quicken products were developed using Borland based code, you can tell just by looking at the visual style of the apps.  But when it comes to Fortran and Cobol see Dijkstra, he said they were dreadful languages 30 years ago and he was right.

Comment: I don't understand how either of these comments are relevant to what  I posted...

Answer (score 1):

- Any project that needs direct hardware access, like drivers, operating systems
- Any project where better performance is a competitive advantage, like games, simulations
- Any project that needs a small footprint, like embedded systems

Answer (score 0):

Check out the click modular router. Written completely in C++ (with some C where necessary)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of micro ISVs are (enthusiastically) using C++ for almost anything you can think of.

It isn't maintained regularly, but [here is a list](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Quality_Applications_Built_With_CppBuilder) of apps written using C++ Builder.  I was pleasantly surprised to see WinRAR and Partition Magic.

Comment: You know what's funny. Click on the link that list Dephi Software, it's SEVERAL pages long. "No one uses Pascal or C anymore." Intel doesn't support Python, Java, PHP, or any of the Politically Correct languages, they have a C compiler. Maybe even a fortran compiler. "But that's just obsolete." Read quotes as sarcasm.

Comment: Yeah, Delphi rocks and it's seeing a resurgence over the past few years.  That said, C++ developers deserve respect.  They also have a stake in the "native vs managed" argument.

Comment: The whole arguement that there are better languages availible is really not very practical approach to programming.  If Delphi works for a developer, and is still supported by the vender why would you migrate your entire codebase to a different language?  Are lamda functions going to make your code anymore readable or mantainable?  No, as matter fact some of the highly praised functionality that is included in the "Advanced" languages have been forbidden in every coding standard I've read.

Comment: Religious arguments aren't practical.  Discussion about which tools or languages are best suited to a given situation, on the other hand...

Comment: If you have a large codebase, not built on the same paradigm as a "Advance" languge whole migration with out bussiness case to do so is unwise.  A valid bussiness would be targeting a different system not support by your current tools.  If you're code's in Delphi and you want to target say Google's Andriod, then migrating to Java would be a perfectly valid choice, due to the design phylosophy of insulating the applicaton from the instruction set such that you can run on both Arm and 0x86 based systems, both running Android.

Comment: However the runtime which is written to make this possible on both x86 and ARM systems will be written and maintained in on of the "less Advance" languages such as C,C++ or Even possibly D these days I'd add Objective C, but I don't know that anyone other than Apple really use that.

Answer (score 0):

I just interviewed with a company that has C++ programs using VS5.0 as they keep planning on phasing the C++ apps out, so updating is not needed.  After 12 years you would expect that they would just upgrade their compiler.

If you want to use DirectX the you have to use C++ now, as MS dropped support for a Managed DirectX API.

As was mentioned, in the embedded world C++ or C is the primary languages.

If you work in a system that cannot crash, then you will may use C or C++ and just don't use new or malloc, but use arrays, so that you won't have any memory leaks, which can be a likely reason a long running process may run out of memory and crash.

If you are going to do a great deal of kernel level programming then C or C++ makes more sense as there will be some functions to call that will be incredibly difficult to call from C#, for example.

Comment: Use vectors and smart pointers to avoid memory problems, not arrays.  It isn't a complete solution, but it's a lot better than arrays and raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

We do these projects in c++:

- Simulation
- Game
- GIS tools

if you need performance, you should use c++...